# Task :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease FAILED Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I have implemented `Firebase` `crashlytics` as suggested. I have put this in my app level `release` build variant:

```
firebaseCrashlytics
  {
    mappingFileUploadEnabled true
  }
```

but when I start to build signed `apk` I am always getting this error

> Task :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'.

> Expected file collection to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.

If I set `mappingFileUploadEnabled` to `false` then release `apk` builds successfully. I have searched a lot but couldn't find a work around. Anyone can help?

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I am also getting the same issue.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution? Other than setting mappingFileUploadEnabled to false.

Comment: What's your android studio version?

Comment: I couldn't fix this issue, my android studio version is not updated to 4 yet.

Comment: In your release build variant, is the `minifyEnabled` property set to `false`? Or do you even have it declared?

Comment: in my case in "edit configurations", I unchecked "Allow parallel run" and it worked

Comment: Any solution for same?

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Error: "Crashlytics could not find Google Services plugin task: processReleaseGoogleServices. Make sure com.google.gms.google-services is applied BEFORE com.google.firebase.crashlytics. If you are not using the Google Services plugin, you must explicitly declare googleServicesResourceRoot inputs for Crashlytics upload tasks."

I had something like this in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

changed it to this and voila! it works:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 30):

I faced the same event today.The reason for this to happen is as follows.

If minify true is set, obfuscation will be applied at build time and mapping.txt will be created.

If minify false, it will not be obfuscated at build time and mapping.txt will not be created.

If you set mappingFileUploadEnabled true in the minify false state, the Firebase SDK will try to upload mapping.txt to Firebase even though mapping.txt is not created at build time.
The result is an error.

So, if you set minify false, you have to set mappingFileUploadEnabled false, if you set minify true, you need to set mappingFileUploadEnabled true or false (when mappingFileUploadEnabled false, the crash log on Firebase was obfuscated. It may not make much sense as it will be displayed in state).

- Hint

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_7

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#enable

Comment: it looks like there is no need to mappingFileUploadEnabled to true when minify is true (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android&%3Bhl=da&hl=ro#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_7)

Comment: For me it would fail when generating a signed APK, only, so I had to [disable the upload, entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64115676/1540350)., otherwise it would say "Socket closed" and "Task :app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease FAILED" and I don't know why. This is only a temporary solution, I'm not sure why the socket closes. This is on a Flutter app. The fun part is that it would work after restart until I decide to create a debug build again.

Comment: `minifyEnabled false && shrinkResources false` Solved for me

Answer (score 13):

In my case I received the error because I wasn't connected to **the internet**. Fixed it by connecting to the **internet** and my build release worked perfectly for my Flutter App.

Comment: Yes, same here. I was having slow internet connectivity at the time of the first attempt to build the APK. So after trying it for a second time, it worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

I have resolved this issue by moving the following line from bottom of the page to top in build gradle.

Previous Settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

New Settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

And the issue is resolved.

Comment: Good call. Not only from the bottom of the page to the top, but 'com.google.gms.google-services' should be on top of 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

Answer (score 8):

Just **change sequence** of crashlytics, apply plugin as below :

```
// Put Google Service
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// After that the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Comment: Congratulations, actually changing the order solved this specific problem.  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask'). > No value has been specified for property 'googleServicesResourceRoot'.

Answer (score 3):

Decreasing the version of the following

```
classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.0"
```

to 2.6.0 solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was not adding `com.google.gms:google-services` at all. The project is in Flutter and Flutter Firebase documents do not mention this.

Add these to `android/build.gradle` (check the latest versions on the internet):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
```

Add these to *at the very end* of `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

For some reason, even if you have generated `lib/firebase_options.dart` with `flutterfire`, the plugin still wants `google-services.json` file you have got from Firebase. Paste that file into `android/app/` directory. And it builds for release.

Comment: for me 

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

should be on the top of your build.gradle. otherwise the error likely occurs

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the bottom of your build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced several times, and there is a different solution i have.

First of all:
You need to open android module of that project.

```
Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio.
```

And then go to Gradle Scripts, find gradle.properties (Global properties) and remove this code

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with GuardSquare's Dexguard solution. Order of your plugins should be,

```
plugins {
    // Google Services Plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // Firebase Crashlytics Plugin.
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    // Dexguard Plugin
    id 'dexguard'
}
```

This way the uploading process of your mapping file is going to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

In **gradle-wrapper.properties** adding the below block solved issue for me. Note: These properties **should not be added to project level gradle.properties**

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```